# PCA preprocess parameter in caret's train function

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, cross-validation, r-caret

I am conducting `knn` regression on my data, and would like to:

a) cross-validate through `repeatedcv` to find an optimal `k`;

b) when building knn model, using `PCA` at `90%` level threshold to reduce dimensionality.

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
data = cbind(rnorm(20, 100, 10), matrix(rnorm(400, 10, 5), ncol = 20)) %>% 
  data.frame()
colnames(data) = c('True', paste0('Day',1:20))
tr = data[1:15, ] #training set
tt = data[16:20,] #test set

train.control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=3)
k = train(True ~ .,
          method     = "knn",
          tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10), 
          #trying to find the optimal k from 1:10
          trControl  = train.control, 
          preProcess = c('scale','pca'),
          metric     = "RMSE",
          data       = tr)
```

My questions:

(1) I notice that [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622242/pass-pca-preprocessing-arguments-to-train) suggested to change the pca parameter in trainControl:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.8))
mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = Sonar, method = "pls",
              trControl = ctrl)
```

If I change the parameter in the trainControl, does it mean the PCA is still conducted during the KNN? [Similar concern as this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/pca-and-k-fold-cross-validation-in-caret-package-in-r)

(2) I found another [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/number-of-principal-components-when-preprocessing-using-pca-in-caret-package-in/123800) which fits my situation - I am hoping to change the threshold to 90% but I don't know where can I change it in `Caret`'s `train` function, especially I still need the `scale` option.

I apologize for my tedious long description and random references. Thank you in advance!

(Thank you Camille for the suggestions to make the code work!)

Comment: Don't have a ton of experience with `caret`, but it looks like `preProcess` should be an argument to `train`, not a function. Change `preProcess(c('scale','pca'))` to `preProcess = c('scale','pca')`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> I notice that someone suggested to change the pca parameter in
>   trainControl:

```
mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = Sonar, method = "pls",trControl = ctrl)
```

> If I change the parameter in the trainControl, does it mean the PCA is
>   still conducted during the KNN?

Yes if you do it with:

```
train.control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=3,preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.9))

k = train(True ~ .,
          method     = "knn",
          tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10), 
          trControl  = train.control, 
          preProcess = c('scale','pca'),
          metric     = "RMSE",
          data       = tr)
```

You can check under preProcess:

```
k$preProcess
Created from 15 samples and 20 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (20)
  - ignored (0)
  - principal component signal extraction (20)
  - scaled (20)

PCA needed 9 components to capture 90 percent of the variance
```

This will answer 2) which is to use preProcess separately:

```
mdl = preProcess(tr[,-1],method=c("scale","pca"),thresh=0.9)
mdl
Created from 15 samples and 20 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (20)
  - ignored (0)
  - principal component signal extraction (20)
  - scaled (20)

PCA needed 9 components to capture 90 percent of the variance

train.control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=3)

k = train(True ~ .,
          method     = "knn",
          tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10), 
          trControl  = train.control,
          metric     = "RMSE",
          data       = predict(mdl,tr))
```